# My macbook fell and shut off. Is my laptop okay?

Tags: laptop, battery, macbook-pro

**Scenario**

Yesterday I placed my laptop on the couch while I went into the other room to get something. I left it plugged in with the battery charged to 90%+. When I came out the laptop was on the floor with the display off and I assumed it was in standby but after pressing some keys I was presented with a critically low battery image. I also smelled a small amount of smoke, the kind that I've only smelled when small electronics received too much voltage and subsequently burned out.

I plugged the laptop back in and turned it on, it was at 1% battery. I nervously let it charge and unplugged the magsafe power at 10% to check the discharge time - the discharge took as long as usual. I plugged the laptop back in letting it charge to 100% and it seems to be fine now.

What could have happened, did the battery somehow short out from the fall? Is a 1 second ~100% to 0% discharge of a LI-ion battery possible with serious consequences? I'm about to be traveling for 6 months and am nervous of the reliability of this laptop now. Should I replace parts / buy a new laptop? Many thanks.

**Equipment**

- Macbook Pro mid 2015
- [replacement battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0753GJ4N7) (installed 2019)

Comment: I would say there is a good chance your battery is to blame.  It looks like it’s a cheap generic Chinese battery.

Comment: I suggest you get Apple to service it and make sure any defective parts (Battery most likely) and then provide you assurance that you can travel reliably.